# Plotting log odds against mid-point of category

Tags: stata, logistic-regression

I have a binary outcome variable (disease) and a continuous independent variable (age). There's also a cluster variable clustvar. Logistic regression assumes that the log odds is linear with respect to the continuous variable. To visualize this, I can categorize age as (for example, 0 to <5, 5 to <15, 15 to <30, 30 to <50 and 50+) and then plot the log odds against the category number using:

```
logistic disease i.agecat, vce(cluster clustvar)
margins agecat, predict(xb)
marginsplot
```

However, since the categories are not equal width, it would be better to plot the log odds against the mid-point of the categories. Is there any way that I can manually define that the values plotted on the x-axis by marginsplot should be 2.5, 10, 22.5, 40 and (slightly arbitrarily) 60, and have the points spaced appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, I achieved the required graph as follows:

1. Recategorised age variable slightly differently using (integer) labels that represent the mid-point of the category:

   ```
   gen agecat = .

   replace agecat = 3 if age<6

   replace agecat = 11 if age>=6 & age<16

   replace agecat = 23 if age>=16 & age<30

   replace agecat = 40 if age>=30 & age<50

   replace agecat = 60 if age>=50 & age<.
   ```
2. For labelling purposes, created a label:

   ```
   label define agecat 3 "Less than 5y" 11 "10 to 15y" 23 "15 to <30y" 40 "30 to <50y" 60 "Over 50 years"

   label values agecat
   ```
3. Ran logistic regression as above:

   ```
   logistic disease i.agecat, vce(cluster clustvar)
   ```
4. Used margins and plot using marginsplot:

   ```
   margins agecat, predict(xb)

   marginsplot
   ```

Comment: No need to apologise. In fact, Stack Overflow [encourages people to answer their own questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). I edited accordingly.